# how to create custom banner layout widget in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-enterprise

[image]**Categories row widget:**

How to make a widget so I could create rows with categories.

- Each row, I can choose how many images in the row (1, 2 or 3).
- Each row, I can choose how much percent each image takes.
- Each row, I can choose if there are spaces between the images.

The widget allows to upload images to the row and give each one a category link and text.

I am using magento 1.9.0